# replace cases contain a certain word with another word and replace all other cases with a third word in R

Tags: r, replace, grepl, mutate

My data are in a text file with about 100 columns, but for now I'm focusing on the location column. I need to change this column so that values containing "ref" should be replaced by "reference", and all other locations (that not contain "ref") should be replaced by "test".

I'm using the `grepl()` function for replacing all location that contain "ref", but it does not work. Also, I can't find a function that can replace "all other locations" with "test":

```
library(dplyr)

farmdata<- read.delim("C:/Users/Documents/farmdata.txt")

farmdata %>% mutate(location_new = case_when(grepl("ref", location) ~ "refernce"))
```

Comment: Can you decribe that "does not work" part in more detail? Is there an error, is the result different than expected? Also, can you include a sample from your dataset? Output of `dput(head(farmdata))` should be enough, ideally it should include locations from both criteria. Though generating a small sample from your description and running `farmdata %>% mutate(location_new = case_when(grepl("ref", location) ~ "refernce", .default = "test"))` works as I would expect it to.

Comment: Thank you for replay, when I use this code I don't get any error but there is no change in my data. I would like to create a new column in my table with new data that contains only "reference" and "test" in location_new-column.

Comment: If you are saying that there is no change in output, I'm afraid there's not much we can suggest without seeing some samples from your data (that `dput` output ...) . If you are expecting `farmdata %>% mutate( ... )` to change your `farmdata` , then you are missing an assignment here, `farmdata <- farmdata %>% mutate( ... )`